# What's the wildcard for dot in bash?

Tags: bash, wildcard

I have files like 0001.file1.email.data.spam.txt and 0001.file1.email.data.spam_1.txt

Now I want to delete all files end with "_1.txt", I tried to use "rm -rf *spam_1.txt", but it cannot find the files. Maybe because * cannot viewed as dot.

Comment: `*spam_1.txt` should work as expected. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: to delete in subdirectories maybe : `find . -name '*spam_1.txt' -delete`

Comment: *spam_1.txt, it showed No such file or directory

Comment: find . -name '*spam_1.txt' -delete.   This one works, verified. I don't know why rm *spam_1.txt doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dot is a literal character which simply matches itself.

The `*` wildcard matches any sequence of characters, and the `?` wildcard matches any single character, but wildcard matching will ignore files which *start* with a dot unless you have [`dotglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) enabled (it is off by default).

You can easily examine what files are being matched by a wildcard expression with something like

```
printf '>>%s<<\n' *spam_1.txt
```

(The `>>`...`<<` decoration is just to make it easy to see any leading or trailing whitespace, and isn't strictly necessary.)

In the absence of `nullglob`, the above will print the wildcard itself if it doesn't find any matches. Also check out [`failglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) which causes an error to be printed and the command to be aborted if the wildcard doesn't match anything.

Comment: This is a useful way to examine what is being matched. Although I find it produces false positives when there are no matches, for instance `printf '>>%s<<\n' *absent_1.txt` prints `>>*absent_1.txt<<` - (i.e. no files named `absent_1.txt` exist, yet this indicates otherwise).

Comment: Use `nullglob` and `failglob` to control the behaviour of globs if they don't match anything.